# Noetherian ring question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring and $I$ a proper ideal of $R$. Show that $R/I$ is noetherian.

Note: This was the last assignment (due date already passed [April 30] so I'm not directly asking for hw answers) for my introduction to abstract algebra course. I'm posting it here because my professor decided not to post solutions for this last assignment since she'll be busy making the final exam. Still, I feel like these questions are very relevant and may pop up on the final.

Lastly:

Let $f = x^k+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+ \cdots + a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial and $p$ a prime integer. Suppose that $p$ divides $a_i$ for $0 \le i < k$ and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$. Show that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Again, your edit isn't really relevant to this question at all, and should be its own question. However, you may find the Wikipedia article on [Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) helpful.

Comment: Please delete "proper" from the claim ...

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use Correspondence Theorem for Ideals and the definition of Noetherian ring.

Answer (score 1):

Translating it into the language of modules you have that $ I$ is an ideal of $R$ iff it is a submodule of $R$ viewed as a module over itself. Then you can use the proposition which states "Let $ 0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of $R$ modules, then $M$ is noetherian iff  $I,N$ are both noetherian". Obviously in this case you consider $ 0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

The ideals of $R/I$ are in correspondence with the ideals of $R$ containing $I$. So any ascending chain of ideals in $R/I$ corresponds to an ascending chain of ideals in $R$, which you know must terminate since $R$ is Noetherian.